# Decrypt web https-transmitted file manually

Tags: openssl, decryption

When the communication between server and client starts -after a request, the computers agree on an encryption protocol to protect the data, the TLS handshake. The data may not be encrypted on the server, but it should be before sending using the server's private key.

If protocols involves asymmetric encryption (and exchange of public key) files (or the HTTP-body) are encrypted, the browser needs the locally generated private key to decrypt it.

This may be more complicated and I'm open to corrections. But just by checking many of the x509 certificates (by clicking on firefox lock symbol) it seems many certificates involve asymmetric cryptography (maybe this is used to exchange the symmetric keys, and next move on to use symmetric encryption).

Assuming all this:

Is it possible to get decrypt the data sent by the server using our private key and the information on the certificate (by clicking on the lock at the URL bar) to decrypt the file via command line using `openssl`?

(I am not sure where the private key that I use locally to decrypt the file is stored by mozilla firefox.)

I know it should be possible to get the encrypted packets on wireshark, but am not sure about the particular details to decrypt.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. I feel that this is a rather [superuser.se] question. Since it is about the usage of OpenSSL and browsers.

Comment: @kelalaka you are correct. Can we move it?

Comment: Flagged for the mods. wait for some time?

Comment: Short answer: no with the elements stated. Typically, it's needed a secret session key negotiated with the server by Diffie-Hellman key exchange, not stored long term. And OpenSSL would typically not be an adequate tool. There are ways to observe the clear data (the question's "file") : that's a built-in feature in FIrefox (F12/network); or one can install a proxy (e.g. on the browser's machine). I won't migrate the question as is, for it's not precise enough (no stated goal…). For now I closed it as off-[topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It can be improved and reopened.

Comment: The browser (or in general HTTPS client) only generates a privatekey for [EC]DHE-type keyexchanges, and doesn't store it anyplace, and it couldn't ever decrypt anything. All encryption/decryption and MAC-ing in SSL/TLS use a series of up to 6 symmetric keys which are derived from shared secrets -- for older protocols (through 1.2) the premaster and master secrets,  and for 1.3 a series of (usually) two inputs and three 'secrets'. Firefox, and Chrome, will write these session secrets to a file if configured with SSLKEYLOGFILE -- there are already numerous Qs about this. ...

Comment: ... However, the data from a webserver is not encrypted as a single unit, or stored as a file that could be decrypted, although invididual entities, or bodies, _may_ be cached (already decrypted), possibly in files. 
If you did have all the data for a single response in a series of files, and the derived keys, you could decrypt with OpenSSL command line _if_ the protocol is below 1.2, or equal 1.2 but using an older ciphersuite. 
If it used an AEAD ciphersuite in 1.2, which is now common, or used 1.3 which _always_ uses AEAD, OpenSSL commandline does not support that.

Comment: @fgrieu so it's not just the x509 certificate with the server public key, and our own private key? idk how there is more steps needed to encrypt/decrypt

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 what is mac-ing; and also, most of the certfficates I'm reading are using asymmetric encryption, so idk how you say symmetric keys >.<

Comment: we should have access to the private key generated by the browser

Comment: MAC = Message Authentication Code; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Data_integrity . X.509 certificates use asymmetric _cryptography_ but rarely or never asymmetric _encryption_, and SSL/TLS never uses asymmetric encryption for data, see the section immediately above that link. I don't know why you think we 'should' have a browser private key (which sometimes doesn't even exist) but no we don't, and if we did it wouldn't decrypt any data ever, only the symmetric keys do that, as I explained. ...

Comment: ... If you want to know the 'steps' to encrypt/decrypt see for example https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246 (that's TLS 1.2; there are links to earlier and later versions). But what you seem to be imagining is completely unlike and not in any way similar to what actually happens.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 asymmetric cryptography is what I meant. And I think we should access the private key cause that's how we decrypt at least part of the data sent by the server signed by our public key..I think the symmetric keys are encrypted and exchanged  using asymmetric cryptography.

Comment: The _key exchange_ uses asymmetric crypto, yes, though for shared secrets as I described not actual symmetric keys. But there is never a browser/client key that asymmetrically decrypts anything. The old/obsolete plain-RSA key exchange encrypts the premaster secret with the _server_ publickey and decrypts it on the server with the _server_ privatekey. The more common Diffie-Hellman-based key exchanges use keypairs on both ends but only for secret agreement not encryption or decryption. No matter what you think **there is NEVER asymmetric decryption on the client.**